# SnowflakeSQL: How to check stream's schema and log stream data in a separate table if schema check fails?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I am pushing data into my Snowflake database's "raw" table using Fivetran. I have placed a stream on this "raw" table, and when new data comes in, I perform an operation on it and merge that data into a "target" table. The code is displayed below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK "TEST_TASK"
WAREHOUSE = "STREAM_TASK_WH"
SCHEDULE = '1 minute'
WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('TEST_STREAM')
AS
MERGE INTO "TEST_PUBLIC"."TARGET" AS A 
    USING (
    
        SELECT "ID",
        "COL1" || '_' || "COL2" AS "COL1_2",
        "COL2"
        
    FROM "TEST_STREAM"
        ) AS B
        
        
    ON "A"."ID" = "B"."ID"
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT("ID", "COL1_2", "COL2")
        VALUES("B"."ID", "B"."COL1_2", "B"."COL2")
        
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET "A"."COL1_2" = "B"."COL1_2", "A"."COL2" = "B"."COL2";
```

The problem is, if the upstream data's schema changes, then this merge will fail. My questions are:

1. Is there a way to check schema before performing the merge operation?
2. Or is it possible to do a try catch, where if the merge fails, the stream data is logged somewhere else?

Basically, I want to be able to alert myself when a schema breaks, and also store this stream data somewhere else so that it can be cleaned up later.

Thanks for any help or advice.

Cheers

Comment: Have you tried using a stored procedure in your task that does a TRY/CATCH?  And why would you want to log the date for the stream somewhere else?  It's not going anywhere until you fix the MERGE statement and run the task again.  If you do want to log it elsewhere, you could create a different stream with its own task that simply logs everything to a separate table always.  Depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why I didn't see your comment. You make a very valid case. I will try that out. Thank you!